# how to flash error in different model view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, message

I am a bit new to Rails so please bear with me.

I have 2 models Client and Product. Product is dependent, and as such, within the Client show view I created a Product creation form. After successful or unsuccessful creation I return to the Client show view. There I wanted to show any errors if the creation went wrong, but I can't seem to be able to access the @product I used when trying to create the Product instance, to get to its errors. Do I have to pass that @product when redirecting to client_path(client)? And if so, how?

BTW, success works, as I use flash to show that, but with the errors I did want to show them in a different position, above the form. If nothing else works, I guess I should pass the errors to flash, but I don't know how to do that either.

Answer (score 2):

U are right...U have to pass @product when redirecting to client_path(client)..
For example...client_path(client, @product)

You can display error messages in client show page as follow

```
      <% if @product.errors.any? %>
          <div class="alert alert-error">
            <ul>
              <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                  <li> <%= msg %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: I tried this. simply added @product in the redirect (the error display already was there), but no error shows up. is there something else missing? do I have to do something in the controller show method to deal with the newly forwarded instance variable?

Comment: BTW, after thinking about it. I don't know how this is supposed to work. redirect_to is a "command" send back to the browser, in order to send a request for "clients/[id]". How could this add all the data needed for the product error messages??? (not that it wouldn't be possible, but I highly doubt it). Now, the product instance variable has not even been saved, which is why I want to show the error messages in the first place! So it can't just add the product id to the link sent to the browser.